# android preference settings range value

Tags: android, widget, settings, preferenceactivity

I am implementing a preference activity so I can let choices to the user about what my app can and can't do and to define a user profile so I can change the way I request data.

I have one part where I need to show places to the user (restaurant, stores, etc) so I would like to be able to have a "range widget".
Let's say :

```
1 = poor
2 = cheap
3 = average
4 = rich
```

I want the user being able to say I want only store between 1 and 3 so it would need to be a widget with a double "circle" allowing the user to create a range.

Any idea of something like this existing ? (I am pretty sure I already seen something like this in the past but I can't remember where)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [RangeBar](https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar). It sounds exactly like what you need

Comment: Yup, I checked I think I will need to play around with the listener but it should be exactly what I am needed